# Regarding RTC drift

Tags: embedded, hardware, rtc, socket, soc

Basically there are two RTCs:

1.internal RTC

2.external RTC

Internal RTC has no battery backup whereas external RTC has CR2032 battery to maintain time in absence of power supply. For accuracy purposes we are using external RTC.

MCP79411 is the chip used for external RTC. For 12 hr long run sometimes we observe 1 to 3 sec positive drift. Why is this kind of behavior observed, whether this is expected behavior? Can anyone please let me know on this issue.

```
root@123:~# busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 -r; sleep 12h; busybox hwclock  --rtc=/dev/rtc1 -r;
Fri Oct 21 09:05:45 2022  0.000000 seconds
Fri Oct 21 21:05:47 2022  0.000000 seconds
```

In this way we comparing

Comment: Without knowing anything about your system, it can be a hardware issue or software issue. Maybe wrong components were used or PCB design is bad. Maybe crystal has had a mechanical shock. 3 seconds over 12h is only 70 ppm error, not really great but not that bad either.

Comment: Why do you think "sleep 12h" will sleep exactly 43200 seconds under Linux? It is a multitasking operating system, not a real time OS. The kernel timekeeping is not done with a real-time clock either. Your measurement technique with "sleep" is not valid.

Comment: Was one or both RTC chips calibrated for the crystal or external clock that that is being used? Per the data sheet "On-chip digital trimming can be used to adjust for frequency variance caused by crystal tolerance and temperature." If one chip is mounted externally the temperature could be different than the other. Two internal chip registers store timing control and trim data to achieve the best accuracy, if these registers are not correct for the operating parameters this could cause excess drift in one or the other. There is a section in the data sheet on how to calibrate the chip.

Comment: @Nedd  only external RTC chip is calibrated

Answer (score 1):

The first step should be to calibrate the internal RTC. That should minimize differences due to any offsets of the crystal on that system.

Since the [MCP79411 chip](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP79410-MCP79411-MCP79412-Battery-BackedI2C-RTCC-20002266J.pdf) is all digital the only variable should be the drift of the crystal's frequency mainly due to temperature changes. If the drift is only observed as you say "sometimes" then the issue may be due to temperature variations that only occurs "sometimes" and it affects one RTC system more than the other.

While the chip can trim timing offsets due to the crystal's initial offsets, the trim setting would only be correct for that one crystal and at that one operating temperature. For improved accuracy both RTC systems would need to be in a well maintained operating environment (minimized temperature variations). Alternately a temperature monitor could be used near each RTC that would allows another controlling system to make periodic trim adjustments as the operating temperature changes.